# How to check whether a Node.js service is running - in my case Azurite emulator?

Tags: node.js, azure, unit-testing, azure-storage-emulator, azurite

I am developing a C# application that should run in Azure. I want to use the [Azurite emulator](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite) to test it locally. What I want to achieve is: **Have my tests detect whether Azurite is running and abort quickly with a nice error message if it is not running.**

Apparently Azurite runs on Node.js.

With the old Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator, I can check it like this:

```
public static class AzureStorageEmulatorDetector
{
    public static bool IsRunning()
    {
        const string exePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\AzureStorageEmulator.exe";
        if (!File.Exists(exePath))
            return false;
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {FileName = exePath, Arguments = "status", RedirectStandardOutput = true};
        var process = new Process {StartInfo = processStartInfo};
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        var processOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        return processOutput.Contains("IsRunning: True");
    }
}
```

I want to accomplish something similar with Azurite.

I have installed Azurite like this:

```
npm install -g azurite
```

I run it like this:

```
azurite --silent --location C:\temp\Azurite --debug c:\temp\Azurite\debug.log
```

I notice that the Azurite command-line application has no parameter that tells me whether it is already running. And when I start Azurite from the console I don't see any process or service in Task Explorer called anything like "azurite". So I don't know what process I'm supposed to check for.

**EDIT**: Apparently Azurite runs on Node.js. There is indeed a process called `node.exe` running, but that's not a sufficient condition. Can I query my running Node.js instance and get it to tell me what it is doing?

I am on Windows.

Does anyone know?

Comment: can you just check if the port `10000` or `10001` is being used by `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the comment by Ivan Yang and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33211614/4290962) I did this:

```
private static bool IsAzuriteRunning()
{
    // If Azurite is running, it will run on localhost and listen on port 10000 and/or 10001.
    IPAddress expectedIp = new(new byte[] {127, 0, 0, 1});
    var expectedPorts = new[] {10000, 10001};

    var activeTcpListeners = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpListeners();

    var relevantListeners = activeTcpListeners.Where(t =>
            expectedPorts.Contains(t.Port) &&
            t.Address.Equals(expectedIp))
        .ToList();

    return relevantListeners.Any();
}
```

**EDIT**: Alternatively, check out this thread on their GitHub for other possibilities: https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/issues/734