# Is there a way to specify the local port to used in tcpClient?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am currently using this function call to create my tcpClient:

```
clientSocket = new TcpClient("localhost", clientPort);
```

But the `clientPort` is the server's port.

Is there a way for me to specify the client port using tcpClient?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [constructor overload that takes an IPEndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f(v=VS.100).aspx) allows you to bind the internal Socket of the TcpClient to a specific port:

```
IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ipLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, clientPort);
TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(ipLocalEndPoint);
clientSocket.Connect(remoteHost, remotePort);
```

Comment: In testing recently, I needed to use a slightly different line to connect: clientSocket.Client.Connect(remoteHost, remotePort); .  Using clientSocket.Connect would change the clientPort on me.