# How do I open a TCPClient with a given source port?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

First off, I don't want to do this in production! I need to test whether someone else's implementation of a protocol on top of TCP is causing issues.

I want to use a certain outbound port over and over for multiple TCP sessions. Windows normally increments the port for each new session, and I want to circumvent this for testing. How can I set the outbound port of a TcpClient?

Comment: Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869840/is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-local-port-to-used-in-tcpclient

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That worked, and better yet, gave me the data I was looking for when I tested it!

Comment: Is there anyway that I can accept a comment as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to another post ([Is there a way to specify the local port to used in tcpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869840/is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-local-port-to-used-in-tcpclient)).  You need to use the constructor overload that takes an `IPEndpoint` in order to specify the local port to use.