# c# TCPclient set IP

Tags: c#, httpclient, port

I'm trying to send a packet using httpclient

```
TcpClient tc = new TcpClient(ip, 4500);

            string s = "A7007000601D3B00";

            byte[] arr = new byte[s.Length/2];
            for ( var i = 0 ; i<arr.Length ; i++ ){
             arr[i] = (byte)Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(i*2,2), 16);
            }

            NetworkStream stream = tc.GetStream();
            stream.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
            tc.Close();
```

The problem is that it sends from port 47109, however i need to send the packet using port 46324. How do i set this?

Comment: Possible duplicate. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869840/is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-local-port-to-used-in-tcpclient

Comment: It doesn't work, getting an error on clientSocket.Connect(remoteHost, remotePort);

Comment: Made an answer to explain the reason why, although you didn't say what the error was I think that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of the TcpClient constructor that allows you to bind it to a specific local IP address and port. See [the documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The reason the example at [Is there a way to specify the local port to used in tcpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869840/is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-local-port-to-used-in-tcpclient) is not working is probably because the first address on the list is not actually the local machine ip address. Something like this might fix the issue and pull the proper local IP address:

```
string remoteIP = "x.x.x.x";
IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First();
IPEndPoint ipLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 47109);
TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(ipLocalEndPoint);
clientSocket.Connect(remoteIP, 4500);
```