# fo-DICOM: How to specify the local outgoing port in DicomClient?

Tags: c#, .net, dicom, fo-dicom

There is way for `TcpClient` to assign local outgoing port as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869840/is-there-a-way-to-specify-the-local-port-to-used-in-tcpclient).

Is it possible to have the same functionality for [fo-DICOM](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom) [`DicomClient`](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/blob/development/DICOM/Network/Client/DicomClient.cs)?

This is necessary because the server is listening for a connection from a specific client port only.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is applicable to older (4.0.1.0 or nearby) versions of fo-DICOM. With latest version, the classes and methods mentioned in this answer are deprecated.

---

Using overload of [`DicomClient.Send`](https://fo-dicom.github.io/html/565babbf-a156-8c12-33f9-89a863c7338d.htm) method, the [`INetworkStream`](https://fo-dicom.github.io/html/3f437665-ab27-4670-f296-c3cca9d71dcf.htm) can be used to provide local outgoing port while working as SCU using fo-DICOM.

As an example, there are four methods available for CSTORE as SCU. First two are:

```
public void Send(string host, int port, bool useTls, string callingAe, string calledAe, int millisecondsTimeout = 5000);
public Task SendAsync(string host, int port, bool useTls, string callingAe, string calledAe, int millisecondsTimeout = 5000);
```

The `host` and `port` are remote host and remote port. None of it accept `IPEndPoint` as parameter.

Now, look at other two methods:

```
public void Send(INetworkStream stream, string callingAe, string calledAe, int millisecondsTimeout = 5000);
public Task SendAsync(INetworkStream stream, string callingAe, string calledAe, int millisecondsTimeout = 5000);
```

Those accept `INetworkStream` which looks like below:

```
public interface INetworkStream : IDisposable
{
    string LocalHost { get; }
    int LocalPort { get; }
    string RemoteHost { get; }
    int RemotePort { get; }
    Stream AsStream();
}
```

This allow providing `LocalPort` to you. You need to write implementation for that interface. Not sure if [`DesktopNetworkStream`](https://fo-dicom.github.io/html/17c98b0c-6bc8-8736-8b66-7c40c9115727.htm) (implementation of `INetworkStream`) can be used directly.

Answer (score 1):

You have raised an [issue on github](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/issues/1109). Following is the feedback from there:

> This is currently not supported. You can work around this limitation by implementing your own `NetworkManager`, and taking heavy inspiration from the existing `DesktopNetworkManager` and `DesktopNetworkStream`. In `DesktopNetworkStream`, the `TcpClient` is created. That is the place where you would need to make your own custom changes.

Looking at the [reply to my comment](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/issues/1109#issuecomment-699959020) there, it appears that the issue is now fixed and the feature is now available.