# How to get the number of open TCP connections held by a certain process in .NET

Tags: .net, winapi, windows-7, pinvoke

I need to monitor the number of open TCP connections held by a single process on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine from .NET 4.0.

This article describes the undocumented Win32 API method "AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack" that accomploshes this task on 32 bit windows:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/iphlpapi.aspx?display=Print

But this fails on my machine (presumably because I am on 64 bit) with:

> Unable to find an entry point named
>   'AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack' in
>   DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'.

How can we do this on 64 bit Windows?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570098/in-c-how-to-check-if-a-tcp-port-is-available

Comment: @Mikey Cee undocumented Win32 API method "AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack"

[AllocateAndGetTcpExTableFromStack function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365804(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might get a good start via [System.Net.NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.aspx). In particular, [IPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections.aspx).

However, you will find that this library does not expose the PID, so there is no way to narrow it down by the particular process associated with each connection. I'm guessing it will be much easier to simply parse the output of a console `netstat -ano` into a collection of managed objects, and use a simple LINQ query to pull out the specific connections you need based on process ID. However, I wouldn't recommend this if you're going to be doing it often, as it would be a very slow method.

You may also try the PInvoke for `GetExtendedTcpTable()` in the DLL you reference above. I don't have my x64 box to test, but it could be a simple deprecation of the particular function you're trying to call.

Comment: Thanks, yes, the method is now called GetExtendedTcpTable().  I found a nice wrapper for it here: http://www.timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstatexe-with-c/

Comment: this is the working link https://timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstat.exe-with-c/