# Get all TCP-connections opened by application using C#

Tags: c#, process, tcp, connection

How to find all tcp connections opened by specific application, maybe by process id or smth. like this? I use C#

Comment: Check out if this helps: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400610/how-to-get-the-number-of-open-tcp-connections-held-by-a-certain-process-in-net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This project can help you :[Getting active TCP/UDP connections](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/iphlpapi.aspx)