# Identify whether the QuickFix is using primary or secondary host to connect

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I am making use of QuickFix/N

With an initiator/Client app does anyone know if there is a way to identify if the quickfix app is using Primary Host SocketConnectHost=xxx and SocketConnectPort=yyyy  or Alternative/Backup/Secondary Host i.e. SocketConnectHost1=rrr and SocketConnectPort=zzz to connect to the server/acceptor.

Looking at the QuickFix Config tutorial i dont see anything that lets me find out.

http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/configuration.html
http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for that, but the information is known inside QuickFIX/N.  It does log it, here: https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/master/QuickFIXn/Transport/SocketInitiator.cs#L226

If you want to dig this information out, you can either modify QuickFIX/N to make some private things public (look for `socketEndPoint`), or implement a logger which captures the relevant phrase, or do some system-level introspection, i.e. use a system API to ask "What TCP connections do I have open now," like this: [Get all TCP-connections opened by application using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145361/get-all-tcp-connections-opened-by-application-using-c-sharp)