# WCF programmatic incorporation of service endpoint address

Tags: c#, wcf, endpoint

i need to connect 2 instances of the same wcf application to each other (for testing scenario ).

each client exposes a service endpoint  and also as the ability to connect to the same service 
exposed by his peer .

**the end point exposed on each client :**

```
 <services>
    <service name="BackGammonClient.ClientService">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8081/ClientService" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="" contract="Contracts.Client.IClient" />
    </service>
  </services>
```

the problem is that each client exposes the exact same endpoint since they are all running on the same localhost and are given the same port .

how can i dynamically apply a  port for each instance of the Client application ?

i was thinking of how i could check if the default endpoint is already taken 
and apply some running Port number to attach to the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically configure your endpoint.  See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647110.aspx

This stack post covers detecting if a port is free:

[In C#, how to check if a TCP port is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570098/in-c-how-to-check-if-a-tcp-port-is-available)

Here's another link with some programmatic endpoint configuration:

http://en.csharp-online.net/WCF_Essentials%E2%80%94Programmatic_Endpoint_Configuration

So, something like:

```
string svcUri = String.Format("net.tcp://localhost:{0}", port);
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
Binding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding( );
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyOtherContract),tcpBinding,
svcUri);
host.Open( );
```

Comment: the msdn article seems over complicated ,
all i need is to assign a value to the address in the endpoint tag
i am not creating a proxy on the other side using the svc tool 
i use the service via a channelfacotry

Comment: I added another link that seems more streamlined

Comment: thanks , i'll post an answer of what i ended up doing
simple but not to conventional i'd like to hear your feedback