# how do i find an available port before bind the socket with the endpoint?

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, port

I'm developing a server-client application that uses 3 ports [TCP SOCKET .Net 4.0]..
So the application gives the user the choice to set the port for the main socket only. but I want to let the server application to automatically find available port for the other 2 sockets so it sends the port value to the client using the main socket connection. then the client connect to the other socket using the received port value.

here's a little explanation:

the main socket listens on a configurable port. this socket accepts client to start send/receive commands. **(file explorer/task manager/properties/shutdown/chat)**

the second socket is for **file transfer** only to transfer files and it closes when its done.

the third socket is only for receive/send a **screenshot.**

*[i know you might say that i should use the same socket for file transfer and screenshot but its a little complicated. i just use separate sockets for each one of them.]*

so how do i find an available port before bind the socket with the endpoint? something like this :

```
int port = 10000;
bool isAvailable = false;
while(!isAvailable)
{
    try
    { 
        // check if the port is available to use.
        isAvailable = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        port++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be !isAvailable, otherwise it won't even enter the while-loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570098/in-c-how-to-check-if-a-tcp-port-is-available

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If the port number doesn't matter you could pass 0 for the port to the `IPEndPoint`. In this case
the operating system (TCP/IP stack) assigns a free port number for you.

```
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                         SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.1"), 0)); // Pass 0 here.

Console.Out.WriteLine("Assigned port: {0}",
                      ((IPEndPoint)sock.LocalEndPoint).Port);
```

As @GrokSrc pointed out in the comments section you should of course dispose the socket when you're done with the socket by using the `Dispose()` method or the `using` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I used it.  Btw, don't forget to dispose the socket if you're actually going to use the port!