# How to get information about all active TCP connections via .net

Tags: .net, tcp, .net-remoting

By chance, I came  around the `IPGlobalProperties` class. Because of interest, I played around a little and tried to make an application that shows the current network activity.

With `IPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections` I get the current TCP connections. And because also closed connections (TIME_WAIT) are contained within the result of `GetActiveTcpConnections`, I thought that this would give me an overview of the whole TCP-communication of the last seconds or minutes.

However there are connections from which I know they exist, but they never appear in the result of `GetActiveTcpConnections`.

What am I missing here? How can I get a list, similar to the “Network Activity List” from task-manager?

*As an additional information, the requests go to an internal device and the response to this requests always returns correctly. The requests are done by the WebClient-class from the same app. Surprinsinlgy, if I do netstat -ano, they also do not appear. However in Task Managers Resource Monitor, I can see them*

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51262610/1866828 as it contains your answer.