# TCP listener start exception in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, tcplistener

I create a TCP listener by using the code below:

```
TCPListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
```

I start to listen TCP devices by using the code below:

```
TCPListener.Start();
```

But here, i don't control if the port is in use. When the port is in use, program gives an exception: "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.".

How do i handle this exception? I want to warn user that the port is in use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a try/catch block around  `TCPListener.Start();` and catch SocketException. Also if you are opening multiple connections from your program, then its better if you keep track of your connections in a list and before opening a connection see if you already have a connection opened

Answer (score 4):

It's not a good idea to get an exception to check whether the port is in use or not. Use the `IPGlobalProperties` object to get to an array of `TcpConnectionInformation` objects, which you can then interrogate about endpoint IP and port.

```
 int port = 1234; //<--- This is your value
 bool isAvailable = true;

 // Evaluate current system tcp connections. This is the same information provided
 // by the netstat command line application, just in .Net strongly-typed object
 // form.  We will look through the list, and if our port we would like to use
 // in our TcpClient is occupied, we will set isAvailable to false.
 IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
 TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

 foreach (TcpConnectionInformation tcpi in tcpConnInfoArray)
 {
   if (tcpi.LocalEndPoint.Port==port)
   {
     isAvailable = false;
     break;
   }
 }

 // At this point, if isAvailable is true, we can proceed accordingly.
```

For details please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570098/in-c-how-to-check-if-a-tcp-port-is-available).

For handling the exception you will use `try/catch` as habib suggested

```
try
{
  TCPListener.Start();
}
catch(SocketException ex)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Catch it and display your own error message.

Check the exception type and use this type in catch clause.

```
try
{
  TCPListener.Start();
}
catch(SocketException)
{
  // Your handling goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a `try catch` block.

```
try {
   TCPListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
   TCPListener.Start();

} catch (SocketException e) {
  // Error handling routine
   Console.WriteLine( e.ToString());
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use try-catch blocks and catch the SocketException.

```
try
{
  //Code here
}
catch (SocketException ex)
{
  //Handle exception here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering that you're talking about *exceptional* situation, just handle that exception with suitable `try/catch` block, and inform a user about a fact.