# Select IP Addresses which use a specific port

Tags: web, ip, port, ip-address

My idea here is create a website where the user is able to click a button which will look into the IP Addresses to see which one is using a certain port, for example:

I want to search for the IP Addresses which are communicating with the localhost that are using the port #3620 (which is obviously being used) and a code will show all the IP Addresses.

My question here is to see if this is possible and if it is, can someone give a brief idea of how this could be done?

Comment: *All* of the IP addresses?  That's a pretty big target.

Comment: Or at least IP addresses that communicate between the local computer or is it the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For seeing if a port is open check out this:
[In C#, how to check if a TCP port is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570098/in-c-how-to-check-if-a-tcp-port-is-available)

You could even loop over all port numbers for an IP address and check to see what ones are open.

```
 TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
 try
 {
    tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 9081);
    Console.WriteLine("Port " + 9081+ " Open");
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Port " + 9081+ " Closed");
 }
```