# Temporarily lock port for testing purposes

Tags: c#, port, tcpclient, tcplistener, tcp

In my project I have a class that checks all ports at localhost and returns true if port is free and false if it is not. The solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/570461/1685878)

**I need somehow to test it. Is there a way to temporarily use the port and then to free it back?**

I've tried to use **[TcpListener Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xt2x8705(v=vs.110).aspx) with no success**. If I use **[TcpClient Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8s2yca91(v=vs.110).aspx)
I get System.Net.Sockets.SocketException** *No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:myPort.*

Here's the code I use:

```
class TestPortLocker
{
    public TcpClient client;
    public TcpListener listener;

    public void Lock(int port)
    {
        client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect("localhost", port);
        //listener = new TcpListener(port);
        //listener.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        client.Close();
        //listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I've tried to use TcpListener Start with no success."?

Comment: @usr My code showed that port was free

Comment: Well, then that code had a bug. What could that bug be?

Comment: @usr That code works well. When I launch some application which uses the port, code shows me that the port is in use.

Comment: So why did you say that the code showed "that port was free"? You said that you had "no success".

Answer (score 1):

You can write a unit test to examine your code. Here's a little pseudo-code for your unit test method and supposed method under test.

Suppose you have a method for this class that you want to test:

```
public class PortManager 
{
    private _portChecker = portChecker;
    public PortManager(IPortChecker portChecker)
    {
       _portChecker = portChecker;
    }

    public bool PortsAreFree(int start, int end)
    {
        for(int i = start, i <= end; i++)
            if(!_portChecker.IsPortOpen(i))
                 return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now to test this method you can use a mock for IPortChecker:

```
[TestFixture]
public class PortManagerTests
{
    [Test]
    public void PortsAreFree_APortIsLocked_ReturnsFalse()
    {
          var mock = new Mock<IPortChecker>();
          mock.Setup(x=> x.IsPortOpen(77)).Returns(false);

          var portManager = new PortManager(mock.Object);

          Assert.Equal(true, portManager.PortsAreFree(1, 76));
          Assert.Equal(true, portManager.PortsAreFree(78, 200));
          Assert.Equal(false, portManager.PortsAreFree(1, 200));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: But is there a way to test IPortChecker logic? I would like it to be more like integration test.

Comment: What exactly are you doing in your code under test ?